# Structure map exceptions erros in call stack?

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, structuremap

ive built my whole application with any erros but when i ran my project in chrome i got this error:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  208
>
> Requested type NoteSeal.NoteSealCoreWeb.Core.IProfileAttributeService is not configured in StructureMap
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: StructureMap.StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  208
> Requested type NoteSeal.NoteSealCoreWeb.Core.IProfileAttributeService is not configured in StructureMap

Source Error:

```
Line 21:             _profileRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileRepository>();
Line 22:             _profileAttributeRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileAttributeRepository>();
Line 23:             _profileAttributeService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileAttributeService>();
Line 24:             _levelOfExperienceTypeRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILevelOfExperienceTypeRepository>();
Line 25:             _userSession = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserSession>();
```

This is the whole class:

```
namespace NoteSeal.NoteSealCoreWeb.Core.Impl
{
 [Pluggable("Default")]
  public class ProfileService : IProfileService
  {
    private IProfileRepository _profileRepository;
    private IProfileAttributeRepository _profileAttributeRepository;
    private IProfileAttributeService _profileAttributeService;
    private ILevelOfExperienceTypeRepository _levelOfExperienceTypeRepository;
    private IUserSession _userSession;
    public ProfileService()
    {
        _profileRepository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileRepository>();
         _profileAttributeRepository =  
      ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileAttributeRepository>();
        _profileAttributeService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProfileAttributeService>();
        _levelOfExperienceTypeRepository = 
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILevelOfExperienceTypeRepository>();
        _userSession = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserSession>();
    }

    public Profile LoadProfileByAccountID(Int32 AccountID)
    {
        Profile profile = _profileRepository.GetProfileByAccountID(AccountID);
        List<ProfileAttribute> attributes = new List<ProfileAttribute>();
        LevelOfExperienceType levelOfExperienceType;
        if (profile != null && profile.ProfileID > 0)
        {
            attributes =   
      _profileAttributeService.GetProfileAttributesByProfileID(profile.ProfileID);
            levelOfExperienceType =
_levelOfExperienceTypeRepository.
     GetLevelOfExperienceTypeByID(profile.LevelOfExperienceTypeID);

            profile.Attributes = attributes;
            profile.LevelOfExperienceType = levelOfExperienceType;
        }
        return profile;
    }

    public void SaveProfile(Profile profile)
    {
        Int32 profileID;
        profileID = _profileRepository.SaveProfile(profile);
        foreach (ProfileAttribute attribute in profile.Attributes)
        {
            attribute.ProfileID = profileID;
            _profileAttributeRepository.SaveProfileAttribute(attribute);
        }

        _userSession.CurrentUser.Profile =  
        LoadProfileByAccountID(_userSession.CurrentUser.AccountID);
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know why this error could appear n this document

Comment: <StructureMap>
  <Assembly Name=" NoteSeal.NoteSealWeb" />
  <Assembly Name ="NoteSeal.NoteSealCoreWeb" />
</StructureMap>

Comment: Most likely you have not instructed the StructureMap container how to instantiate an `IProfileAttributeService`. You'll have to post your registration code.

Comment: And BTW: you should use [Constructor Injection](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/DI-Patterns-Constructor-Injection.aspx) instead of calling `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` from your actual code.

Comment: How do you configure Structurmap ? With default conventions ?

Comment: i use structure map as a assembly reference and created a xml file to reference it